# UITextView not becoming first responder in ios 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, ios7, uitextview

I am using the following [control](https://github.com/brandonhamilton/inputtoolbar)  in a viewcontroller i want to show the keyboard when user opened the view so I tried to call this method from the viewcontroller

```
[self.inputToolbar.textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

But the keyboard does not show when opened the view. So i called the becomefirstresponder in the place where the textview is allocated [you can see the allocation page here](https://github.com/brandonhamilton/inputtoolbar/blob/master/UIInputToolbarSample/Classes/UIInputToolbar/UIExpandingTextView.m) i called like this

`[internalTextView becomeFirstResponder];`

Now it works in iOS6 but in iOS7 it does not works

Comment: Have you try sample application given https://github.com/brandonhamilton/inputtoolbar i tried ant it works,(i.e keyboard show while clicking on text box. (tested in both iPad and iPod)

Comment: @Jageen i need to open the keyboard with out clicking it. when navigated through the keyboard should open automatically . yes i tried the sample code but not works

Comment: ohho ok my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**By using sample code** 
I write below code in`UIInputToolbarViewController.m` >  `loadView`

```
[self.inputToolbar.textView.internalTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

And it's working fine.

**Code**

[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much bhai. I never expected that i would be so simple. +1 for the solution